# Delphi + BlueStacks: Your Android device does not support the selected target platform architecture

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, arm64, bluestacks

I just tried BlueStacks 5 and I think I can debug/deploy directly in it from Delphi. In BlueStacks I setup an **Android 64 image** and set the ABI to only **ARM 64**. When I try to deploy my Android 64 app from Delphi to BlueStacks I receive the error message:

> Your Android device does not support the selected target platform architecture

But if I deploy the Android 32 version of my app (on the Android 64 instance of BlueStacks with only ARM 64 ABI activated) then it works!

What did I miss?

Comment: What have you selected as `ABI setting` in the instance? See also `5.` on this page https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058929011-Application-Binary-Interface-ABI-in-BlueStacks-5 Have you checked the created APK file regarding the included libraries?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, I think delphi can produce only ARM bitness and not Intel (for android). So except if the interface of bluestack is very baad (it's say it's run a 64 image of android with a ARM 64 bit abi) I must be able to upload only 64 bit version of my app in bluestack

Comment: @Robert : I have selected only ARM 64 bit abi, this why i can't understand why i can not install the 64 bit version of my app BUT i can install the 32 bit one :(

Comment: Yeah, I completely messed up what I wanted to say... AFAIK BlueStacks can run either 32 bit or 64 bit Android OS on Intel CPU. To run Delphi applications on 64bit Android OS it needs to emulate 32bit or 64bit ARM CPU. It is possible that it can emulate 32bit ARM but not 64bit,

Comment: But, if BlueStacks actually has option to select 64bit ARM (I missed that part of your question), then Delphi application should be able to run on it.

Comment: BTW, not that it helps you, but 32bit Android ARM applications can always run on 64bit ARM and 64bit Android OS.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar thanks! yes now we agree, it's really strange that the 64bit arm version of bluestack accept only 32 bit version of the app made in delphi. something wrong with the 64 bit version produced by delphi

Comment: Wonder if this is useful (to use Intel instead which should be faster): https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2015-october-running-android-intel.html